# My PHP username line is not checking if the username already exist in my db

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I used this line of code to check if the username already exist in my database, if the user does not exist it creates it- if it does `echo 'username already exist'`

```
if(!DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))){
    //create user
    DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, :username, :password, :email)', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':email'=>$email));
    echo "SUCCESS!";
} else {
    echo 'USER ALREADY EXIST';
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What exactly is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you don't mind try this and see.

```
$pWord = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$chkUname = $dbconnect -> prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$chkUname -> bindParam(':username', $username);
$chkUname -> execute();

$rowCoun = $chkUname -> rowCount();

if($rowCoun > 0){
    echo "USER ALREADY EXIST";
}else{
    $addUsr = $dbconnect -> prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, :username, :password, :email)");
    $addUsr -> bindParam(':username', $username);
    $addUsr -> bindParam(':password', $pWord);
    $addUsr -> bindParam(':email', $email);

    if($addUsr -> execute();){
        echo "SUCCESS!";
    }else{
        echo "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an sql query you don't get true or false. With this line you will get 0 or 1 line of data. You have to save the response from the query and then you can access the number of lines that where returned. Check if this number is 0 => username not in database.

Comment: i have already tried that with :     if(explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT'){
     
    $data = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $data;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear the thing you want, if you want to check user already exist or not, just change `SELECT username` to `SELECT COUNT(id)`

```
if (!DB::query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
    //create user
    DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, :username, :password, :email)', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':email'=>$email));
        echo "SUCCESS!";
} else {
    echo 'USER ALREADY EXIST';
}
```